# Load and render HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a unique situation where I need to completely load, run associated scripts, and render an HTML page in the background. This is a full html page.

Here's how I'm currently doing it which isn't working:

I get the page using a GET XHR call and store it as a `string` in a variable called `template`. Once I have the `string` I use `JQuery.parseHTML` to parse it into an array of elements (including the scripts) and from there filter until I get the element I need, storing it in a variable called `content`. Then I insert that element into the DOM.

The problem I'm having is that the DOM elements in `content` are not completely rendered because their scripts haven't been run.

Here's my code:

```
function (template) {
    var jTemplate = $($.parseHTML(template, document, true));

    console.log(jTemplate);

    var content = jTemplate.filter('.page-wrap').contents()
        .filter('#content-wrapper').contents().filter('#content')
        .contents().filter('#main-content');

    console.log(content);

    $("agency-journal-content").replaceWith(content);
}
```

How can I go about running the scripts and rendering the DOM in the background and then inserting it into the current document or DOM that the user is seeing.

Comment: What is the execution trigger for the script included in the HTML string?

Comment: Try adding a function name, like `function load(Template){...}` and then run `load(Template);`

Comment: @TyQ the function is being run... I only copied the relevant parts here. You guys don't need to see where it's being run because that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: `$("agency-journal-content")` should probably be `$("#agency-journal-content")` -- you left out the `#` that indicates an ID.

Comment: @Barmar nope, I'm replacing an element called `agency-journal-content` and that is working fine. Please re-read my question for the problem I'm having.

Comment: Can you show an example of `content`?

Comment: @Bamar right click and press view source on any webpage. All of that including the body and header tags are what's in `template`. Then `content` is an element with the ID `main-content` that was extracted from `template`.